# TextView singleLine="false" without specifying defined width

Tags: android, layout, textview

I'm trying to get a textview to take have mutiple lines and cut at the size of the parent.

```
<TableLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <TableRow android:gravity="left">
<TextView android:id="@+id/deal_title"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:singleLine="false"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" style="@style/dealrowtitle" />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

This does not force it to only be the width of this view. The text goes off screen.

The text view will only force if I give it a pixel count.

Comment: What kind of ViewGroup is the TextView in?

Comment: how about you show us the style and the complete xml

Answer (score 1):

You could use `android:maxWidth="10dip"` to prevent the textview from growing more than the specified width.